# Can a (male) taxi driver drive a female (non mahram), while being alone?

Tags: halal-haram, work, men-women, non-mahram

These two ahadith say that it is forbidden for man to be alone with a non mahram woman:

> The Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: 
>   “No man should be alone with a woman unless there is a mahram with them.”
>
> *Narrated by al-Bukhaari (1862) and Muslim (1341).*

And:

> And he (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: 
>   “No man is alone with a woman but the Shaytaan is the third one present.”
>
> *Narrated by al-Tirmidhi (1171) and classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi.*

Basically, in a taxi job, you would drive people around. So if you were a taxi driver and a man and you pick up a woman by herself, which I'm guessing would be  haram because you would be alone with the woman. Is that true?

But if the woman needed to go somewhere emergency like if she went into labour etc or just heard their relative is in hospital and she has no mode of transport that will get their in time apart from a taxi, will it be allowed?

Comment: Please edit your title to something; "is it haram for a man to drive taxi while the only customer is a woman...?" To ask if taxi jobs are haram is like asking if its haram to have eyes, because you can look at women (with bad intentions) with the eyes

Comment: @Kilise  The question isn't just aimed at male taxi drivers but of both genders so the example I gave could be the opposite so it would be a female driver and a male customer but most taxi drivers are male and Saudi Arabia sharia law doesn't allow women to drive.

Comment: if you wish, you could answer your own question with the point of view that you tend to follow: [IslamQA - Bus driver being alone with a woman](https://islamqa.info/en/10374) (in your question and answers)

Comment: And adding this https://islamqa.info/en/130815 (from your point of view) you could also answer the emergency issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's forbidden for non-mahram men and women to be alone together (khulwah).  However, the question is if being alone in a taxi constitutes khulwah given that people can see inside taxis.  There's a difference of opinion (see below).

---

[SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2011/02/21/can-a-taxi-driver-serve-the-opposite-sex-transport-customers-to-haram-locations-or-transport-customers-carrying-haram-items/) (Hanafi) write:

> As a taxi driver, **it is permissible for you to take a female customer**, based on the following considerations. It would not entail seclusion (khalwa) that is forbidden, as long as the streets taken have people there that can easily see inside the cab. Avoid secluded streets, and avoid doing so at night.

(See also Qibla.com from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/35653).)

[Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/2986) (Salafi) write:

> A taxi driver is bound to pass through empty streets or highways, and the structure of the car conceals most of the body of a person riding in it. Furthermore, there is no guarantee that a forbidden conversation will not take place, or that there will not be an agreement to do something forbidden. ... **A taxi driver should not accept a female passenger who is alone**, except in cases of emergency such as accidents and the like.

(See also [another Islam Q&A fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/10374).)

Shaikh Muhammad Naasirud-Deen al-Albaanee (Salafi) writes:

> A woman riding alone with a taxi driver that is not a mahram to her may encounter herself in privacy (khulwah) in the sense that some of the forbidden matters that occur normally in khulwah (privacy), are likely to occur in such a situation. Furthermore, there is no third person that is with them. But from here, **I do not hold that it is khulwah (privacy), but instead it is a motive and an incentive for fitnah (temptation)**. And this fitnah is not found in the other example in which there is another woman present or another man. Indeed the occurrence of fitnah in this situation is less likely than in the first situation. [Al-Asaalah, Issue #10]

(Sourced from [TheClearPath.com](http://www.theclearpath.com/viewtopic.php?t=77&start=12))

[Al-Islam](https://www.al-islam.org/code-ethics-muslim-men-and-women-sayyid-masud-masumi/rules-related-socializing)  (Shia) write:

> **If there is no intention of having pleasure or excitement and there is no chance of falling into corruption, then the act of sitting in itself is not a problem.**